# #ifdef _DEBUG in main function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros, visual-studio-debugging

Does `#ifdef _DEBUG` in the main function has any sense if I am working on *visual studio 2013* ?

If yes, what it is for ?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
#ifdef _DEBUG

//creating some objects, using  functions etc;

#endif
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`#ifdef DEBUG` or `#ifdef _DEBUG` are used to handle some code that you use for *debugging* purposes. If you add `#undef _DEBUG` or similar to this at the very beginning of your code, the compiler will skip the code contained in `#ifdef DEBUG /* bla bla */ #endif`.

If you're

> //creating some objects, using  functions etc;

*inside* this block and thinking this will work, I assure you, **it won't** until you include `-D_DEBUG` in compiler's options during invocation.

Answer (score 1):

for example it can be used to do stuff only in debug compilation ;)
Check your flags specifically to VS, in linux for example, you add NDEBUG to non debug builds.. so check your project properties.. compile command line.. etc..

Comment: `NDEBUG` is actually used in the standard for the behaviour of `assert`, so you might consider it for more than just Linux.