# Is debugging code not going to production in c++?

Tags: c++

I am reading this piece of code. For example:

```
    if(-1!=ids) {
            len = ids - curi;
            string match_word(content, curi, len);
            bool rejudge = false;
            if(isJudgeAm) {
                rejudge = judgeAmbiguity(curi,len,segmentStartPosIndex,m_segmentAndPosId);
            }

            if(rejudge) {
#ifdef _DEBUG
                int32_t startpos = segmentStartPosIndex[curi];
                int32_t endpos = segmentStartPosIndex[curi+len-1];
                int32_t firstWStart = m_segmentAndPosId[startpos].second.first;
                int32_t firstWEnd = m_segmentAndPosId[startpos].second.second;
            
                int32_t secondWStart = m_segmentAndPosId[endpos].second.first;
                int32_t secondWEnd = m_segmentAndPosId[endpos].second.second;

                cout<<"pattern and segmentWords ambiguity:"<<string(content.c_str()+curi,len)<<
                            "|"<<content.substr(firstWStart,firstWEnd-firstWStart)<<"|"
                            <<content.substr(secondWStart,secondWEnd-secondWStart)<<endl;
#endif
            }   
            else {
#ifdef _DEBUG
                cout<<"match word="<<match_word<<endl;
#endif
                ...
            }
        }
```

If rejudge=true, it simply prints out a bunch of information, but didn't take any actions.

Comment: On a release build both if and else statements won't be executed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#ifdef \_DEBUG in main function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260027/ifdef-debug-in-main-function)

Comment: So the compiler will simply skip this section of debugging code, even if variable values are changed in this code and it has no impact on the logic?

Comment: Assuming the project is on windows and visual studio, yes the code will be skipped on release build. On debug build or when you debug, the code will be executed.